# How to render HTML and graphics on top of existing PDF using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I have these inputs:

- an HTML page
- an Existing PDF, and some more HTML/stuff I want to draw on top of that PDF (text, html, circles)
- an HTML Page

I want to render a 3-page PDF, and have them all be displayed on in a single PDF.

In other words, my question is **How do I use an existing PDF as a template for more input**

Can this be done from PHP and how?

Comment: You're likely got get lots of "What have you tried" and "Show us some code" comments, so let me be the first: What have you tried? Do you have any existing code to show?

Comment: I currently use TCPDF library to generate PDFs from HTML.  I use FPDI library to reuse existing PDFs as a template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, with wkhtmltopdf, you can't modify/edit an existing PDF.

Comment: shucks ... I can see a "work-around", such as modifying existing HTML to "add more HTML", but I have existing drawings in PDF that I can't recreate in HTML, so that casts that tool out for me.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

With a custom XSL using this code, you could easily do it.

http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.APIDoc.Usage

The backend rendering engine is XSL FO based which supports injecting a PDF as a background image.

So easy, I did you a sample. Go to this page:

http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.CustomTipsTricks.BackgroundImages

Click the Open-> PDF button.
The "Top Secret" PDF is injected as a background, the HTML overlayed on top. You can use this solution to combine your HTML, PDF and HTML+PDF in any way you wish.

In fact, with HTML, this Javascript and a little customization you could have a document that was:

start document

```
format HTML div
format HTML div with this PDF background
format another HTML div
inject this entire PDF
format another HTML div with a different PDF background
inject a different entire PDF
...
```

end document